# name of IPA /ɚ/

Tags: terminology

The IPA symbol /ə/ is named "[schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa)". For example, the "i" in "philosophy" /fəˈlɑːsəfi/.

A similar symbol is /ɚ/ or /ər/, the sound of "er" in "water". How about this symbol? Does it have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have a name: schwar, pronounced either /ʃwɚ/ or /ʃwaɹ/.

From my language teaching experience, however, it's not a very commonly known term, so you can also use "r-colored schwa" or "rhotic schwa", since there are a few symbols with the little r-coloring marker, [◌˞](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel#:%7E:text=In%20phonetics%2C%20an%20r%2Dcolored,frequency%20of%20the%20third%20formant.), and they do not have special names.